# Looking for a visual website editor that lets me import my existing site

Tags: web-development, website-design, wysiwyg, squarespace

A company I work for has a static HTML website that's already built (custom coded using Bootstrap 3 framework), and now they'd like for non-tehnical people to be able to edit it too, using a visual editor.

A did a little bit of research:

- [Pinegrow](https://pinegrow.com/) - seems nice, but they'd prefer an online service
- [Squarespace](https://www.squarespace.com/) - also seems nice, but when I enabled the developer mode in order to migrate our existing site, it seemed like there are quite a few things to learn and do just for the migration

Ideally, I'd want to copy/paste our HTML (using absolute CSS and JS assets' URLs so the service can find them), the service would import those assets into its own system and let people change things visually without us maintaining those JS/CSS any longer. 
Also, it must let us inject custom JS/CSS.

Is there such a service?